# Bind to model from child directive where model has not been resolved at compile-time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular ui for bootstrap for its modals:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

I am opening a modal with a `controller` and `templateUrl` with:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: $scope.templateUrl,
    controller: $scope.controller,
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
        formModel: item
    }
});
```

where `formModel` is the model I will use in the modal.
Here is the controller for the modal:

```
app.controller('commentCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'formModel', function ($scope, $modalInstance, formModel) {
    $scope.formModel = {};
    var loadFormModel = function () {
        if (formModel !== undefined) {
            $scope.formModel = formModel;
        }
    };
    loadFormModel();
}]);
```

This modal has child directives and needs to pass properties of `formModel` to them

template:

```
<div>
    <child model="formModel.Comment"></child>
</div>
```

but `child` is created before the modal's controller has loaded `formModel`. Inside the child I want to use `model` as:

```
app.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<textarea ng-model="model"></textarea>',
        link: linkFn,
        controller: controllerFn,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        }
    };
});
```

**Edit:**

I've found that I can do:

```
<div>
    <child model="formModel" property="Comment"></child>
</div>
```

...

```
app.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<textarea ng-model="model[property]"></textarea>',
        link: linkFn,
        controller: controllerFn,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            property: '@'
        }
    };
});
```

Is there a better way to do this without the extra attribute?

**Edit 2:**

I have found where the bug is:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kUWYDvjR8YArdqtQRHhi?p=preview

See `fItem.html` for some reason having any `ng-if` causes the binding to stop working. I have put a contrived `ng-if='1===1'` in for demonstration

Comment: What exactly happens with two-way binding in your case when you do model="formModel.Comment"? Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @estus I have added a Plunker. `ng-if` seems to break the binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `ng-if` directive [creates new inherited scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), so the bug is just a common scope prototypal inheritance pitfall.

The most concise way to get around it is to use controllerAs syntax in conjunction with `bindToController`, the avoidance of undesirable scope inheritance side effects is the most common use case for them. So it will be

```
app.directive('fItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'fItem.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        }],
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        }
    };
});
```

and

```
<div class="input-group">
    <textarea ng-if='1===1' ng-model="vm.model" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting. I will need to do more reading into this to fully understand it, but yes, Now adding `vm` before all of my scope properties fixes this issue. Thank you

Comment: @tic There's a load of questions on prototype inheritance, I suggest to check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs , it is quite prominent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do. If you need just to wait until variable is resolved, you need just use promise: (Here is simple one using $timeout, if you use i.e. $http - you ofc dont need $q and $timeout)

```
  resolve: {
    something: function () {

      return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('Hello, world!');
        }, 3000);
      });
```

Then modal will be opened only after promise is resolved.
http://plnkr.co/edit/DW4MzIO4ej0JorWRgWIK?p=preview

Also keep in mind that you can wrap you object, so if in scope you have $scope.object = {smth : 'somevalue'} :

```
  resolve: {
    object: function () {
        return $scope.object;  
    });
```

And in modal controller:

```
$scope.object = object;
```

Now object in initial controller scope and object in modal scope point to same javascript object, so any time you change one - another changes. You are free to use `object.smth` in modal template as usual property. And as soon as it will change you will see changes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've created an entire skeleton Plunker of the part I am working on, and it **is** working. I have no idea why it is failing in my application. http://plnkr.co/edit/kUWYDvjR8YArdqtQRHhi?p=preview The model binding in fItem is not working, and no changes I make will be reflected in my controller (This is working in the Plunker). The example allows to modify existing entries and add new ones.

Comment: I have added a Plunker to the original post. `ng-if` seems to break the binding.